# Unable to submit App with Auto-Renewable Subscriptions for a non Newsstand App

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have never had a problem submitting a non Newsstand App with Auto-Renewable Subscriptions.
But I just started seeing this error when I try to submit app for review:

> Free and Auto-Renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions are only
>   available for apps with Newsstand enabled. Remove this In-App Purchase
>   before you disable Newsstand.

[image: Screen capture of error in iTunes Connect]

Anyway to get around this error without delete "Auto-Renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions" ?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem right now. My app is not new and has had auto-renewable subscriptions for many months and through many updates now. This is the first time I'm seeing this.

Comment: I guess I'm not the only lucky guy, I suppose Apple is suggesting to use Non-Renewable subscriptions instead.

Comment: I think it's a bug in iTunes Connect and that they are hopefully working on a fix. Did you fill out the contact form to make them aware of the issue?

Comment: For now I switched to Non-Renewing Subscriptions, I'll contact them anyway.

Comment: Having the same issue right now. Let's hope it's just a bug and not a policy change.

Comment: This happens for me even _after_ I switched to a non-renewing subscription. Definitely seems like an iTunes Connect bug at this point.

Comment: I called iTunes Connect tech support and they are looking into the issue. They asked me to provide very detailed steps to reproduce it. It might make sense for others to do the same so that they see that this is not a one-off issue. You can find the phone number if you click on "Contact Us" in iTunes Connect, then select "iTunes Connect Upload ..." and click the second "contact us" link there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just was on the phone with apple developer support. They said that this is a known issue with itunes connect and they are hoping to resolve it by the middle of today. (we are having the exact same issue with an application that is already in store with recurring purchases; we are currently unable to update the app because of this error)

EDIT: Issue is resolved for me

Comment: It is now resolved for me.

Comment: yeah its now working for me too

Comment: I changed all my auto-renewing subscriptions to non-renewing to submit, I should have waited...

Comment: @HiroshiHorie can you just attach your old build? I just rolled back in iTunes Connect to the original build once my non-renewing submission also didn't work...oh hey, I should probably go change the code back as well.

Comment: @owenfi I don't believe it has anything to do with the binary