# Newsstand enabling issue in iTunes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have submitted new version of my app(version 1.1) on iTunes on 02 June now it is in waiting for review state when I try and change some text in my
 App description. It says Newsstand has to be enabled for auto renewable and in-app purchase subscriptions.
**In-App Purchase
Free and Auto-Renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions are only available for apps with Newsstand enabled. Remove this In-App Purchase before you disable Newsstand.**
[image]

Should i removed build from iTunes or is there any way to resolved this issue?

Comment: Same issue here with the app approved and waiting for Developer release. I bet it's a bug on iTunes Connect

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633074/unable-to-submit-app-with-auto-renewable-subscriptions-for-a-non-newsstand-app

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed now. I just submitted again and it worked.